# Unit Test con status code 415 Unsupported Media Type de respuesta en HapiJS

Tags: javascript, hapijs

Estoy haciendo el `unit-testing` con `lab` para un servicio en `hapijs`. El servicio lo que hace básicamente es solicitar un archivo:

```
server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/file',
  config: {
    payload:{
      output:'stream',
      parse: true,
      allow: 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  },
  handler: function(request, reply){
    reply({ message: 'File saved' });
  }
});
```

Siendo su `unit-test`:

```
var request = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/file',
  payload: {
    file: {
      value: fs.createReadStream('input.csv')
    }
  }
};

lab.test('it return the default message to file index', (done) => {
  server.inject(request, (response) => {
    Code.expect(response.result.message).to.match(/File saved/);
    Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
    done();
  });
});
```

El caso es que al ejecutar el unit testing me retorna `{ statusCode: 415, error: 'Unsupported Media Type' }`. Por lo que pienso que debo indicarle en los headers el content-type pero no estoy seguro de cuales sean los valores que se necesitan y en dónde deben ir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luego de investigar encontré la respuesta utilizando `form-data` y `stream-to-promise`:

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
var streamToPromise = require('stream-to-promise');

lab.test('it return the default message to file index', (done) => {
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('input.csv'));

  streamToPromise(form).then((payload) => {
    var request = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/file',
      payload: payload,
      headers: form.getHeaders()
    };

    server.inject(request, (response) => {
      Code.expect(response.result.message).to.match(/File saved/);
      Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Referencia: [server.inject for multipart/form-data #1711](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/1711)

Comment: ¡Súper duper! también encontré por ahí [este gist](https://gist.github.com/Couto/127ca8a6bd28ecc4a084)

Answer (score 0):

Para añadir los headers a esa petición puedes modificar tu objeto `request` así:

```
var request = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/file',
  headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "..."
      },
  payload: {
    file: {
      value: fs.createReadStream('input.csv')
    }
  }
};
```

Puedes consultar los comentarios en [este issue](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/1543) para ver el ejemplo de un usuario.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, al cambiar el `content-type` por `multipart/form-data` me retorna el error que no tiene un formato apropiado. Encontré una solución usando `form-data` y `stream-to-promise` que ya parsea a un formato reconocible por el servicio.